# How I can remove the Save button in the PDF viewer?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to remove or block the save button on the browser pdf viewer on a page made in wordpress, I try to fix it using embed but when increasing the size of the display returns and the save button appears.

I try to work with this line of code.

`<embed src = "http: //localhost/transferencias/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Zona200.pdf" type = "application / pdf" width = "100%" height = "100%">`

But it did not work, maybe some know about wordpress plugin that allows me to block those buttons.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It´s not possible. This is a browser specific feature and you can´t access those controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the PDF plugin by passing parameters on the query string. Adobe has documentation on [parameters used to open PDF files](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters_v9.pdf). You can hide toolbars, scrollbars, set zoom levels etc. The documentation is rather old, but should still be valid. Using your link above, you would set the src to

```
<embed src = "http: //localhost/transferencias/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Zona200.pdf#toolbar=0" type = "application / pdf" width = "100%" height = "100%">
```

to disable the toolbar (and hide the save button).

Please remember that these parameters are only for Adobe Acrobat plugin. Non-Adobe pdf readers may not respect these parameters.